# string escape characters

Tags: python, string

Can someone explain the following:

```
In [9]: str( """w'o"w""") 
Out[9]: 'w\'o"w'
```

why the double quote has no escape? it does the same thing with or without the escape:

```
In [10]: print ( 'w\'o"w') 
w'o"w

In [11]: print ( 'w\'o\"w') 
w'o"w
```

And in the following two cases there's no escape:

```
In [12]: str( """w'o'w""")
Out[12]: "w'o'w"

In [13]: str( """w"o"w""")
Out[13]: 'w"o"w'
```

but they are still equivalent to their with escape versions:

```
In [14]: str("w\'o\'w")
Out[14]: "w'o'w"

In [15]: str( "w\"o\"w") 
Out[15]: 'w"o"w'
```

Can someone explain to me why Python has this 'inconsistency'? What are the merits of having them?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking about?  Is your question why the values are *displayed* as they are, or is your question why *inputting* the string with or without escapes doesn't change its value?

Comment: my question is answered perfectly by @rmunn 's first paragraph .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the Python console (which includes IPython) shows the value of a string, it does so by printing the `repr()` of the string. `repr()` will produce output that could be parsed by the Python parser, so it will include backslash-escapes when necessary. (And only when necessary). If all the quotes in a string are single-quotes, `repr()` will show you the string with double-quotes around it, necessitating no backslashes. If all the quotes in a string are double-quotes, `repr()` will show you the string with single-quotes around it, necessitating no backslashes. If the string contains mixed single- and double-quotes, then backslashes will be needed.

As for what's going on with the `print()` calls -- they are not printing the `repr()` of the string, they're showing the `str()` value of that string, which is the string itself with no backslash escaping added (and no quotes around it).

So here's what's going on in each of your examples:

```
In [9]: str( """w'o"w""") 
Out[9]: 'w\'o"w'
```

You are getting the value of the string `w'o"w` and IPython is displaying the *value* on the output. So it calls `repr()` on the value, which puts quotes around it and backslashes inside it.

```
In [10]: print ( 'w\'o"w') 
w'o"w
```

You are *printing* the string `w'o"w`, not getting its value. So IPython is displaying the printed string. Note there's no `Out[10]` -- the `print()` function returns `None`, and IPython suppresses output values when they are `None`.

```
In [11]: print ( 'w\'o\"w') 
w'o"w
```

Same thing here: you're *printing* the string, rather than IPython showing you the value. So it uses `str()`, not `repr()`.

```
In [12]: str( """w'o'w""")
Out[12]: "w'o'w"
```

Here you are showing the value of the string, so it gets quotes around it. But no backslashes, since they're not needed to represent the string.

```
In [13]: str( """w"o"w""")
Out[13]: 'w"o"w'
```

Ditto here: no backslashes, since they're not needed to represent the string.

```
In [14]: str("w\'o\'w")
Out[14]: "w'o'w"
```

Ditto here: no backslashes in the `repr()` output, since they're not needed to represent the string.

```
In [15]: str( "w\"o\"w") 
Out[15]: 'w"o"w'
```

And ditto here as well: no backslashes in the `repr()` output, since they're not needed to represent the string.

I hope this helps you understand what's going on a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

When you enclose a string with `single quotes`, you need escape the `single quotes` within the string - otherwise how would the interpreter know if the string is meant to be ended or not?

Conversely, when you are enclosing a string with `double quotes`, you need to escape the `double quotes` within the string.

`"""` enclosing quotes is an exception - it is smart enough to change it's behaviour based on the contents of the string being enclosed. If you enclose a String containing a single quote, it will behave as if you had enclosed it with double quotes. If you enclose a String containing a double quote, if will behave as if you had enclosed it with single-quotes

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonn you have to escape the start/end of string character is so the compiler/interpreter knows that that symbol doesn't mean the start/end of the string scope.

Therefore, If the character is `'`, then `'` becomes a special character, and `"` is not. And vise versa. And if you start it with `'''` or `"""` (multi line string) than neither character is special and thus neither needs escaping.